# Ajax Joomla Module

Tags: ajax, joomla

how to navigate from one page to another in joomla module using ajax

Comment: need more info if you have any demo please put it here

Answer (score 2):

Although your question is a little vague, I'm assuming that you want to load another module, within the same position, rather than just navigate to a new page. If that's the case, you need to look into using Mootools and AJAX to return some HTML, but you would need the module published with the correct permissions first.

Your question is too vague to help any more.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var ajaxUrl = "modules/mod_mapcontent/submit_form.php";

//jQuery("#map-canvas").html('<div class="map-text">Loading Map...</div>');
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ajaxUrl,
    data: {category: 'simple'},
    dataType    : "json",
    async       : false,
    success : function(result){
        data = result;

    }
});
```